# How to connect Kafka consumer channels dynamically using Spring Boot at run time?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

My design Architecture

WebSocket Clients <---> API Manager Component <----> Apache Kafka

I have to design this API Manager Component using Spring Boot. The main function of the component is as follows.

1. Connect with WebSocket Clients (Not an issue)
2. When WS Client is connected, API Manager Component should connect to the relevant Kafka Channel related to that particular Web Socket Client and Consume the data. This should happen dynamically at runtime because API Manager does not know the identities of WS Clients prior to login.

How can I use Spring Boot to achieve this point 2?